# Как подправить jquery slider?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

Как вынести элементы управления слайдером за рамки изображения (показано на рисунке)?

[image]

http://v.testjay.esy.es/

Answer (score 1):

У `.ion-image-slider-popup` убрать `overflow: hidden;` 
ну и двигайте себе на здоровье:

```
.ion-image-slider-popup.opend .ion-image-slider-popup-next {right: -100px;}
.ion-image-slider-popup.opend .ion-image-slider-popup-prev {left: -100px;}
```